# Complex regex pattern not recognizing spaces?

Tags: regex

I have a regex pattern which captures what I want in about 50% of cases, I've found that the cases where it doesn't match it has to do with spaces in the string.  This is with javascript Regex BTW.

**REGEX PATTERN:**

`/\[url="https?:\/\/([a-z0-9-]+\.)*cnn\.com\/newsreel\/showreel\.php\?id=?([^\s]*[^.])?\"\]([^\s]*[^.])\[\/url\]/gi`

**STRINGS TO MATCH ON**

A)   `[url="http://www.cnn.com/newsreel/showreel.php?id=977976"]Test123[/url]`

B)   `[url="http://www.cnn.com/newsreel/showreel.php?id=977976"]Test 1 2 3[/url]`

Now if i try to run this pattern on A, it works A-ok.   But on B, it fails, because of all the spaces.

I think it has to do with my 3rd matching group `([^\s]*[^.])` which I guess isn't catching spaces.  Anyone have any ideas how I can get it match spaces as well?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your 3rd matching group from

```
([^\s]*[^.])
```

to

```
(.*[^.])
```

I.e., you replace `[^\s]*` (zero or more non-whitespace characters) with `.*` (zero or more characters).

Note that this will also allow other whitespace characters, such as tabs and potentially newlines, depending on how the regex is used. If this is too lax, you could opt for `[\S ]*` (zero or more non-whitespace or regular space characters).

Comment: Actually I'm running into an issue with more testing where its capturing extra characters.  How would I use your other suggestion of [\S ]* ?

Comment: Use `([\S ]*[^.])` for the third matching group.

Comment: So whats happening now is that if i make my string: `[url="http://www.cnn.com/newsreel/showreel.php?id=977976"]Test 1 2 3[/url] [url="http://www.cnn.com/newsreel/showreel.php?id=977976"]Test 1 2 3[/url]`  Its matching the whole string as 1 unit.  So 2 back to back [url] schemes is seen as one

Comment: Also with my second suggestion? Should not.

Comment: Yep for me with the second suggestion it still picks these up as one giant url scheme

Comment: OK, difficult to know exactly why without knowing how and in what language you're using these, but using `([\S ]*?[^.])` as your third group should fix it.

Comment: ... and you are the master!  Thx again